# Resource from iframe does not contain style

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have an HTML page that I want to render to another page using an iframe (both pages are running on the same site on development). I succeeded in linking the page using an iframe, but now the page is displaying in the iframe without its styles. What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution... I probably set that 300px width screen should be media query min-width, then I rendered it into the iframe and viewed in a 320px width screen and the iframe in the 320px screen was resized to 90% which made it less than 300px screen and the style did not apply.